# WatchOS 2 best practice for storing/retrieving data

Tags: ios, core-data, watchkit, watchos-2

Is there a best practice for quickly storing and retrieving data on the watch? As a hypothetical, imagine a grocery list. Each time the wrist goes down the app stops. When the user raises their wrist we need to reload the app's state (and our grocery list) quickly into memory. Is CoreData overkill? Is NSUserDefaults good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how much data you are storing. NSUserDefaults has a limit on how much you can store in it. I am using CoreDate in my watchkit app and performance has been great. I would recommend if you are storing a small amount of data then NSUserDefaults would be fine, otherwise look into CoreData.